# NSString Character found

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have on nsstring object in which sometimes phone number gets stored and sometimes email address, i just need to ask that how to find any character suppose @ in a string, when email address is typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could check for @ as a substring

```
if ([string rangeOfString:@"@"].location == NSNotFound) {
  // Number
} else {
  // Email
}
```